# how to integrate TPKeyboardavoiding in swift?

Tags: swift

My app contains several textfield and textview inside of scrollview. for keyboard hide and show i have searching TPKeyboardavoiding in swift.kindly help me anyone for integrating tpkeyboardavoing in swift. i am not unable to add the question. so only i edit this question.

Comment: Is `nsobjectclassname` a variable of type `Class`?

Comment: what u ask? i dont understand ur question

Comment: Don't try to translate ObjC code literally to Swift. All JSON types are value types so you should use a struct rather than a class inherited from `NSObject`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Swift version is as following:

```
let obj = NSObjectClassName()
obj.name = json["name"]
array.append(obj)
```

Comment: how to add the object in array in swift

Comment: its append or add